# Cocos2d-x Version 2.2 CCRenderTexture not rendering image properly on Samsung Tab 4 (model no. SMT231)

Tags: cocos2d-x

I have been trying to draw on touches moved using Render Texture. This is my code:

```
void GameplayLayer::visitSpriteContinuously()
{
   CCRenderTexture*    canvas = CCRenderTexture::create(screenSize.width,screenSize.height,kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA4444);

   canvas->setPosition(ccp(screenSize.width/2,screenSize.height/2));
   this->addChild(canvas);

   GameSprite* drawSprite=GameSprite::gameSpriteWithFile(“circle.png");
   this->addChild(drawSprite);

   CCPoint start = starttouchPosition->getLocationInView();
   start = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->convertToGL(start);

CCPoint end = starttouchPosition -> getPreviousLocationInView();
end = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->convertToGL(end);

float distance = ccpDistance(start, end);
canvas->begin();
for (int i = distance; i > 0; i--)
{
    float difx = end.x - start.x;
    float dify = end.y - start.y;
    float delta = (float)i / distance;
    drawSprite->setPosition(ccp(start.x + (difx * delta), start.y + (dify * delta)));
    drawSprite->visit();
}
canvas->end();
```

}

I am getting the desired result in almost all the android devices that I have tested except Samsung Tab 4. On Tab 4 the sprite drawn is having a dotted sort of pattern even if the base png image used is single solid colour. I have searched a lot, but I didn't find anything useful. If anyone has seen similar issues and has a solution please let me know. Following are the screenshots:

'A' rendered on Other Devices:
[image: Other Devices:]

'A' rendered on Samsung Tab 4:
[image: Samsung Tab 4]

Answer (score 0):

In some device,RGBA4444 format not supported correctly, so in that case , you have to use RGBA8888 format.
So, Just change this line in your code

```
CCRenderTexture*    canvas = CCRenderTexture::create(screenSize.width,screenSize.height,kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA4444);
```

with

```
CCRenderTexture*    canvas = CCRenderTexture::create(screenSize.width,screenSize.height,kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888);
```